# Does Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi support GRUB?

Tags: boot

Is Grub compatible with my Raspberry Pi 5 running Ubuntu 23.1 Gnome 45.2?

Comment: Why do you need grub? Do you want to dual boot?

Comment: Is your downloaded Ubuntu 23.1 OS for ARM or for AMD? ARM does not use GRUB. (I think).

Comment: Hi. No,  Was just asking had problem booting then thought GRUB would help.  Thanks for your help.  Brgds.